# Existence of a certain nodal quartic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

I am reading this (https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~claire.voisin/Articlesweb/Univcodim2invent.pdf) paper of Voisin, but I am having some trouble with the proof of Sublemma 2.8 (it might be something very simple but I don't exactly see it).
Namely, let $S$ be a $k\leq 7$ nodal quartic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and let $Z$ be the set of nodes. Let $\pi:\tilde{S}\longrightarrow S$ be the blowup of $S$ along $Z$. Then one gets that the "principalized" linear series $|\pi^\ast I_Z(4)|$ is nef and big on $\tilde{S}$ (here $I_Z\subset O_S$ is the ideal sheaf of theset $Z$). From here, how can one deduce that there exists an irreducible quartic curve on $S$ which is nodal at $Z$? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The blown-up surface is again a K3 surface, hence nef and big divisors are psuedoample (generated by sections). This is easy to prove, you can also look [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373709) at this paper of Saint-Donat.

- Saint-Donat, B. *Projective models of K3 surfaces.* Amer. J. Math. 96, 602-639 (1974).

A general curve in the considered linear system on $\tilde{S}$ will thus be smooth by Bertini, and its intersection with each exceptional curve will consist of two distinct points, by Bertini again. This means that it projects to a curve on $S$ which is smooth except for nodes at $Z$.